# Large gap between beginning of slide and home page

Tags: html, css, horizontal-scrolling

I'm trying to build a horizontal parallax scroll for my website. However, I end up getting a large gap between the beginning of the slide and where the text of the home page begins. I've tried setting padding to 0, margin to 0, everything to no avail. Any ideas? Here's a screenshot to illustrate what I mean: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3I7v.jpg

HTML:

```
<div id="transition-slide-container">   
  <div id="transition-slide">
   <div id="inner-container>
    <div class="slide" id="home">
        <h1>home</h1>
    </div>
   </div>
    <div class="slide" id="portfolio">
      <div id="inner-container">
        <h1>portfolio</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide" id="about">
       <div id="inner-container">
        <p>about</p>
       </div>
    </div>                  
    <div class="slide" id="contact">
       <div id="inner-container">
        <p>contact<p>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#transition-slide-container {    
    background: #bee1ff;    
    padding-top: 128px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    height: 900px;
    min-width: 400%;    
    z-index: -1;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
div#transition-slide {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.slide {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1620px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
div#inner-container {
    width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Website: andrewgu12.kodingen.com

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you add float:left in your header class, that fixes it

```
div#header {
color: #FFFFFF;
float: left;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
top: 0;
width: 960px;
```

}

Comment: I was referencing the text on the body, where the light blue area is not my menu bar. My question wasn't worded that clearly, I'll add in a screen shot for what I mean.